# How would I remove specific words or text from KQL query?

Tags: kql, azure-resource-graph

I have the following query which provides me with all the data I need exported but I would like text '
' removed from my final query. How would I achieve this?

````
| where type == "microsoft.security/assessments"
| project id = tostring(id),
          Vulnerabilities = properties.metadata.description,
          Severity = properties.metadata.severity,
          Remediations = properties.metadata.remediationDescription
| parse kind=regex id with '/virtualMachines/' Name '/providers/'
| where isnotempty(Name)
| project Name, Severity, Vulnerabilities,  Remediations ```
````

Comment: Please avoid tags' spamming

Comment: At it current state, this question should be closed due to lack of clarity. You can improve it by providing sample data + required results. Both should be in text format.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `replace_string()` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/replace-string-function) to replace any substring with an empty string

Comment: How would I incorporate that into my script like this if I wanted to replace '<br>' with 'Next'?  ``` | extend replaced=replace_regex(str, @'<br> (\d+)', @'Next') ```